ARIMA model with seasonal adjusted series
I want to forecast the series with trend and seasonal components using ARIMA model. But is that posible that I use the seasonally adjusted data for ARIMA model to gain the forecast data, then add the trend and seasonal component to the forecast series?
Or is there any solutions to this method? How to combine the trend into ARIMA model?
The method i am using is to decompose the series using STL-Decompose on Eviews 10 into trend, seasonal and remainder components. Then I use the seasonally adjusted data to forecast using ARIMA model. Next I add the seasonal components to the forecast data to have the final forecast value. Is that possible? I use the Eviews 10 to analyze the data.

Yes. Proposed here: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2010.11.002. Here is a textbook version: https://otexts.com/fpp3/forecasting-decomposition.html
